# Docker mysql had degraded performance after re-install ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, ethereum, ubuntu-server

I use MySQL for the official docker image(Ver 8.0.27) on the ubuntu server(20.04 lts).
And I re-installed the server due to expanding storage.
The versions of MySQL and the ubuntu server are the same.
However, MySQL's performance is quite degraded.

I'm trying to collect addresses of the Ehtereum(This is a kind of crypto currency.) network.
The way to collect that is simple.

1. Get transaction info.
2. Extract addresses(To, and From).
3. If the addresses have been recorded in a MySQL table, then ignore it. If the addresses have not been recorded, then record the addresses.
4. Get the next transaction info.
5. Back to 2.

I execute the above loop by using a program in Typescript(With [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/), [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2), and [Web3.js](https://github.com/web3/web3.js)).
Regarding the `if` statement of the 3rd item in the above list, I use the unique constraint of MySQL, not Typescript.

In short, at first, make the table like below,

```sql
CREATE TABLE `addressList`
 (
  `timestampReadable` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `showUpBlock` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstTransactionHash` varchar(66) DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` varchar(42) DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `addressList_address_uindex` (`address`),
  KEY `addressList2_timestamp_index` (`timestamp`),
  KEY `addressList2_firstTransactionHash_index` (`firstTransactionHash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

And, in the program, run only the following query.

```sql
INSERT INTO addressList values (123456, 123456, 123456, 'hfuwheohg', 'jhfoiehhfs');
```

If the address is unique, the address is recorded, if the address is not unique, the address is not recorded.

The current number of the record is around 160,000,000~.
This may large table, but the program was running at practical performance before the re-install.

So, I can't find the cause of the problem.
Just in case, I run `check table`, but the result seems to be no problem like below.

| Table | Op | Msg_type | Msg_text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ethereum.addressList | check | status | OK |

I tried to set some MySQL configurations like below.

```sql
SET GLOBAL max_connections=1500;
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size=1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

But, the performance is not improved.
I forget the MySQL configuration the first time it launches(I really regret it).

Does anyone know what to do with it?
Please, help me!

Comment: Have you tried using https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mysqltuner.1.html mysql tuner for ubuntu?   What are the max connection opened after running the system for a day or two?  It is possible new storage is considerably slow?

Comment: Try setting `Set Global innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2` to see if the write speed changes.  However, it will not be ACID compliant if this is what is needed.  I think you are setting `soft_buffer_size` and max connections too high. Overall memory allocation is a multiple of number of connections X sort buffer size, plus some other buffers.   Since you are simply writing more into DB,  soft buffer can be small, like 4K.

Comment: See [insert ignore](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) rather than doing checks in application code. Also consider making the `address` either a primary key and/or `NOT NULL`. Large `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_log_file_size` would help.  If you have the container logs some of the system config might be in the logs there.

Answer (score 0):

- If a column cannot be `NULL`, then say `NOT NULL`
- No `PRIMARY KEY` is specified, so one is generated for you.
- If `address` were never `NULL`, then I strongly recommend `PRIMARY KEY(address)` *and* remove `UNQIQUE(address)`
- [potential design flaw] What kind of hashes are you using?  Certain hashes do *not* want a "ci" collation -- they depend on "A" and "a" being different.  Consider changing hashes to ascii_bin.
- [save lots of space] If the hashes are hex strings, consider converting to binary.  For example, any standard UUID will shrink from 36 bytes (of ascii characters) to 16 bytes (of binary stuff).
- (If I understand the data), you have two *very*  random values being indexed.  Before continuing, let me discuss the ramification of that.
- If those "hashes" are 256-bit quantities expressed in hexadecimal (digits and letters only), then `UNHEX(...)` to turn it into `BINARY(32)`.  It is is already in 'binary', then simply store it in `BINARY(32)`.  (As opposed to `VARCHAR(66)`.

Each index (including any `UNIQUE` and the hidden PK) is stored in a "B+Tree".  This structure is well ordered, but by whatever is indexed.

If the `INSERTs` are performed approximately in chronological order, the index on `TIMESTAMP` will have all the activity at the "end" of the BTree.  Such a 'hotspot' is easily cached.  That is, it is very efficient and should never slow down, regardless of table size.

If `firstTransactionHash` is MD5 or SHAnnn or similar, then the values are very random.  Caching of the blocks of its BTree are essentially useless.  So, at some point, the 'next' block needed for the next `INSERT` is very unlikely to be in RAM.  This necessitates an I/O.  I/O is time-consuming.

I don't know what `address` is like, but I suspect its index works like one of the above.

The "randomness" applies whether it is a varchar or binary.

Shrinking the size of the table is the main goal.  But it is only a partial 'fix'.  Eventually, your table will *again* be so big *relative to the cache size* that performance will decline.  The cache size is controlled by MySQL's `innodb_buffer_pool_size`; what is the current value?  That setting is constrained to a large fraction of the RAM available to MySQL; how much do you have?  Check whether Docker is further constraining the "ram" under its control.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I will say `NOT NULL`. I will use `PRIMARY KEY(address)` and remove `UNIQUE(address)`. Regarding `firstTransactionHash`, it is hexadecimal based on `keccak256`. This is the specification of the Ethereum([reference](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/how-to-calculate-the-assigned-txhash-of-a-transaction)). Should I convert it to binary in this case?

Comment: I understood regarding "`INSERT`" `firstTransactionHash`, but how about "`SELECT`" a `firstTransactionHash` from the table? I am using the index to speed up the selecting of 'firstTransactionHash'.
The `address` is a 42-character hexadecimal([reference](https://info.etherscan.com/what-is-an-ethereum-address/#:~:text=An%20Ethereum%20address%20is%20a,e.g.%2C%200x71C7656EC7ab88b098defB751B7401B5f6d8976F.)).
Current `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is `1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 10(10GB)`. My server has 64GB RAM. Other containers are running on this server, but the memory of this server has free space.

Comment: Can you print an example of the keccak256?  If it does not print well, then let's see the HEX() of it.

Comment: I added a bullet item.

Comment: This is an example of the `firstTransactionHash`. `0x8ba39f908731171fe96ee4e700e71d170ef8e651fac7040c4d6adb581582793b`
This seems to have digits and letters only. Can I just `UNHEX()` this?

Comment: Actually, that is a representation of a `BINARY(32)` blob.  The "0x" says so.  (And that explains your mysterious varchar(66).  Ouch -- You may have lost data when storing.

Comment: How does that 66-char string come in?  As a string?  Or something else?

Comment: The string are retrieved as a string.